# Postfix unary increment operation on pointers

Tags: c, pointers, operator-precedence

I newly started working with **C** and **Pointers**. There is a concept that confuses me regarding to unary increment operation on pointers.

```
int num1, *pnum1
num1 = 2;
pnum1 = &num1;
printf("%d \n before: " , *pnum1);
num1 = (*pnum1)++;
printf("%d \n after: " , *pnum1);
return 0;
```

Since the ***unary increment operator*** (++) has greater precedence than the ***dereference operator*** (*), I put ***pnum1** inside braces. What I expect was to see below result:

> after: 3

But it doesn't increment the value of num1. Why would it be the case? Wasn't it suppose to increment the value of num1?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are these constructs using pre and post-increment undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-pre-and-post-increment-undefined-behavior)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is undefined behaviour. You're incrementing `num1` (via `(*pnum1)++`), then assigning the result back to `num1`. The order that incrementing and assigning happen is undefined in this case, so it could get the old value of `num1`, increment `num1`, and then assign the old value back to `num1`, which seems to be what your compiler has chosen to do.

If you try `num1 = num1++` instead, your compiler will probably warn you about this.

The solution is not to do stuff like this, since it's undefined behaviour.

Look up "sequence points" for more information.